# Installing an npm package globally from a forked repo

Tags: node.js, npm, git-fork, loopback4

I have been trying to install loopback 4 cli from a forked repository. But it's always failing. I have tried installing using the following:

npm install -g https://github.com:OnTheThirdDay/loopback-next.git

It fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/local/bin/node /home/aaqilniz/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/aaqilniz/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path /home/aaqilniz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecqMsXe
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command sh -c husky install && npm run -s bootstrap && npm run -s update-ts-project-refs
npm ERR! npm ERR! > @loopback/tsdocs-monorepo@0.2.0 postinstall /home/aaqilniz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecqMsXe/fixtures/tsdocs-monorepo
npm ERR! npm ERR! > npm run build
npm ERR! npm ERR! fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna notice cli v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info versioning independent
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info Bootstrapping 74 packages
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info Installing external dependencies
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info Symlinking packages and binaries
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info lifecycle @loopback/tsdocs-monorepo@0.2.0~postinstall: @loopback/tsdocs-monorepo@0.2.0
npm ERR! npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:943
npm ERR! npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR! npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module '@lerna/project'
npm ERR! npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! npm ERR! - /home/aaqilniz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecqMsXe/packages/monorepo/lib/run-lerna.js
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:773:27)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aaqilniz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecqMsXe/packages/monorepo/lib/run-lerna.js:13:19)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
npm ERR! npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
npm ERR! npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR! npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR! npm ERR!     '/home/aaqilniz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecqMsXe/packages/monorepo/lib/run-lerna.js'
npm ERR! npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! npm ERR! }
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna info lifecycle @loopback/tsdocs-monorepo@0.2.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
npm ERR! npm ERR! lerna ERR! lifecycle "postinstall" errored in "@loopback/tsdocs-monorepo", exiting 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /home/aaqilniz/.npm/_logs/2022-03-15T14_41_12_250Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aaqilniz/.npm/_logs/2022-03-15T14_40_40_094Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a git clone on the project manually and then run npm install -g in the cloned directory instead of targetting the distant directly ? It looks like the automatic git clone in te tmp directory has just failed and that the .git directory can't be resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Peterrabbit. This solved the problem. Though I did it after installing dependencies into the cloned project.